# How long is the main quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am wondering how long the main quest line is?

I'm also wondering how long some of the guild quest lines are, and if you rank up in position in certain guilds/factions like you did in Oblivion?

Comment: Well, if you are a Skyrim developer... just a tad over [2 hours](http://www.destructoid.com/skyrim-s-main-quest-can-be-cleared-in-around-two-hours-213657.phtml)

Comment: @spartacus In general we disapprove of link-only answers. Although that answer does answer this question, I think it would be valuable to answer this question separately, since a Skyrim-only answer can afford to contain more content (as you provided with the Skyrim developer comment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The game technically never ends because they continue to randomize quests after you have completed all of the handcrafted quests.

The main quest itself is supposed to take around [30 hours for an average game](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/06/08/skyrims-main-quest-30-hours-long-additional-content-lasts-two-to-three-hundred-more/).

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE! Do you have a reference for your last statement?

Answer (score 4):

There are three acts with 6-7 quests in each act.

You can find all kinds of info on [quests](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Quests_%28Skyrim%29) on the Skyrim Wiki.  The [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quests) are also a good resource.

The amount of time it takes is completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The main quest is odd, because you'll probably end up doing a few sidequests without realising it. But the story line quest took me three days and I played around 3-4 hours each. So around 9 hours, and I was also a level 12 when I finished, so if you're higher it could be shorter still

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends on how fast you are going, But overall iv'e heard 300+ hours mentioned more than once.

I personally will be finishing every single quest in the game and search every tomb,house etc... Just about 3-4 month's worth of gaming :)

It all boils down to how long you can last in the game,There is no set timelimit or timetable

Comment: You know that missions are infinite and randomly generated... so "finishing every single quest" could take some time

Answer (score 0):

The main quest shouldn't take long if you can conjure Dremora Lords. I was able to get lords in about 15 hours from the start of Skyrim. Also a tip is to get the dragon priest masks while you're there.